# concatMap Adding More Items to Array

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have the following piece of code:

```
public getDomains(): Observable<any[]> {
    const customer = this.storage.getCustomer();
    const apiUrl= this.configuration.getApiUrl(customer);
    return this.http.get((`${apiUrl}/domains`).toLowerCase())
        .map((response) => response.json() || []);
}
```

---

```
const domains = this.myService.getDomains().
    .shareReplay()
    .concatMap((domains) => domains.map((domain) => this.toDomainModel(domain, myObservable)))
    .filter((domain) => this.isValidDomain(domain))
    .toArray();
```

---

My network tab is showing the response from the request as an array with 3 items in it. But somehow, even after removing everything and only leaving the `.toArray()`, it is transformed into an Array with 3 elements, where each element itself is an Array of 3 items. The network response is being duplicated 4 times somewhere.

I call a service method which returns an array of items which I then send through this chain of methods. For some reason, and I believe it may have to do with `concatMap`, I end up with more items than the endpoint originally returned.

I should get 3 items back from the request, and then the filter should remove 2 of those so I should be left with one. I'm fairly new to `rxjs` and am curious as to whether or not this is common behavior with `concatMap`.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've added more code @EleazarEnrique, is this enough? I can provide more if need be

Comment: Your current output and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: I added more text @Harangue

Comment: @IngoBürk Nope, you can give it an iterable and it will flatten it for you. The way it's being used here is a little strange though. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42482824/1008741

Comment: Yeah, I noticed now as well. Deleted my comment. :)

Comment: Sorry @User5842 but there's nothing obviously wrong with your observable, especially with the context we're given. If I had to hazard a guess I would say the issue is related to your subscriptions, but if directly `toArray`'ing the network response is still exhibiting the problem, there's no insight to be had from the code you posted.