# rxjs map parameter is the entire array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

```
public observableA = (id: string): Observable<Array<any>>=>{

}

public observableB = (id: string): Observable<Array<myClass>>=>{
    observableA(metroId).map((x)=>{
         return new myClass(
            x.FacilityName,
            x.ID)
    };
}

export class myClass{
    ID: string;
    Name: string;
    constructor(id: string, name: string){this.ID=id;this.Name=name;}
}
```

ObservableA returns an array of objects,  I'm writing a function ObservableB to return an array of myClass using the returned array of ObservableA.

When I debug this code,
What I can see is 'x' in the map parameter is the entire array from ObservableA, rather than the object elements of the array.

so the properties can't be accessed.

What could be wrong?

**Update:
Is there a way to make the single Observable of Array to an array of Observables so I can process the elements?**

Comment: Was that not what you expected? `Observable.map` is mapping over each item *in the stream*, not in the array that stream happens to contain. You may be confusing it with `Array.map`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh i thought it's similar to lodash's map

Comment: That is also basically `Array.map`, by the looks of it. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/42482705/3001761.

Comment: The edited question is still weird. I doubt that you want an array of observables. I think you don't yet understand the concept of observables and would encourage you to read more about it first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how observables work.

You are getting the whole array because that's what the observable is working with. It's a `Observable<Array<any>>`, so the `map` operator will get a `Array<any>`. If you want to work on one object at a time, your observable should be of type `Observable<any>` (or better, using a concrete class like `Observable<TestClass>`)

You can create an `Observable<T>` from an `Array<T>` using `from`, see this page:
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-from

I don't know how this can be applied to you since you didn't post how `observableA` works.

Here's some resources I used when I learned RxJs:

- https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754
- https://toddmotto.com/rxjs-observables-observers-operators

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the need for a second Observable, maybe this what you want to achieve but let me know if I am wrong, I will update accordingly:

[live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-2c87sb)

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { async } from 'rxjs/scheduler/async';
import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const metroId: string = "IamAnId";
const arry: Array<myClass> = [];
const observableA: (id: string) => Observable<any> = (id: string) => {
    // use your id whatever you want
    return from([
        {
            FacilityName: 'name',
            ID: 'IamAnotherId'
        },
        {
            FacilityName: 'AnotherName',
            ID: 'AlsoHere'
        }
    ], asyn);
}

observableA(metroId)
    .pipe(map(x => {
        return new myClass(
            x.FacilityName,
            x.ID)
    }))
    .subscribe(itemClass => {
        arry.push(itemClass);
    })
```

Comment: this x is the entire array so I'm not able to access the element's property values. I think if observableA returns Observable.from, this would work

Comment: My bad, I was using the wrong creator (of). Observable.of and Observable.from are synchronous by default (that is  why you are getting the whole array from once). But you can change Observable.from to be asynchronous by adding an Scheduler as a second parameter (async).