# Angular CLI - Can't use Array.find() within Observable pipe function

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular-cli

I have the following Code:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { filter, map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';


export function valueInCollectionValidator(collection: Observable<any[]>, propertyName: string) {
  return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> => {
    return collection.pipe(
      filter(array => array.find(e => e[propertyName] == control.value)),
      map(ok => ok ? undefined : { valueNotInCollection: false }),
    );
  };
}
```

When using angular CLI's ng serve, I get a build error:

ERROR in validators.ts (9,29): Property 'find' does not exist on type '{}'.

This is my jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any idea why this won't work?  Thanks!

Comment: What I was actually looking for was a way to take an observable of an array and 'flatten' it into an observable of the inidividual items.  This is solved with using the mergeAll() operator and is answered here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482705/best-way-to-flatten-an-array-inside-an-rxjs-observable

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` method automatically takes in each array element. So in effect, the `array` you are referring to inside the `filter` method is an element of the array `collection` which in your case is an `object`.