# Angular: Flatten / un-flatten nested JSON objects

Tags: javascript, angular

Does Angular have any native functions to flatten JSON data, and then nest it back up? I see code below, just curious if Angular has any embedded library functions. Otherwise I will copy and paste this function into our library.

[Fastest way to flatten / un-flatten nested JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098797/fastest-way-to-flatten-un-flatten-nested-json-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Angular doesn't have that, but RxJs could have something that you can find useful.

[Best way to "flatten" an array inside an RxJS Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482705/best-way-to-flatten-an-array-inside-an-rxjs-observable)

http://alanpryorjr.com/2019-05-15-rxjs-flattening-operators/