# RXJS convert single observable to array of observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have an API (**getNewStories**) that returns the data as an array of `numbers(ids)` such as [1,2,3,4...].
There is another API (**getItem**) that uses the `number(id)` and give its details.

How can I accomplish this with rxjs operators, so that I should only subscribe to it once and it gives me an array of the records with those ids?

I am able to accomplish this using 2 subscriptions, but I want it with one. Is it possible? and if it's, then, how?

```
this.hnService.getNewStories().subscribe(data => {
  // data is [1,2,3,4,5]
  // create an array of observables for all the ids and get the record for that id
  const observables = data.map(item => this.hnService.getItem(item));
  // use forkJoin to combine the array to single results variable
  forkJoin(...observables).subscribe(results => {
    this.stories = results;
  });
});
```

with this I have to subscribe to both the APIs.

Comment: If you ever find yourself doing `.subscribe(() => { ....subscribe();});` in rxjs you know your going wrong. There should only ever be one subscribe to each subscription

Comment: I agree with you, that's why the question is here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were going the right direction with using `forkJoin`:

```
this.hnService.getNewStories()
  .pipe(
    concatMap(data => {
      const items$ = data.map(item => this.hnService.getItem(item));
      return forkJoin(...items$);
    }),
  )
  .subscribe(allItems => ...);
```

`forkJoin` will wait until all source Observables complete and only then emit all results as a single array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using a flattening operator like this.

```
this.hnService.getNewStories().pipe(
            .mergeMap(data => this.hnService.getItem(data))
            .subscribe(res => this.stories = res);
```

Other option can be to create two observable streams and use a combineLatest.

Comment: This would not work as the *data* in mergeMap is an array, and the function getItem takes a number

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have implemented as in the the following snippet: (Yes, `mergeAll` flattens an observable containing an array, for further explanation refer to `@Martin's` post about the [Best way to “flatten” an array inside an RxJS Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42482824/9369606)
)

```js
getNewStories().pipe(mergeAll(), concatMap(this.getItem), toArray()).subscribe()
```

You can try running the following snippet:

```js
const { of } = rxjs;
const { concatMap, toArray, mergeAll  } = rxjs.operators;


function getItem(x) {
  return of({ item : x })
}

of([1, 2, 3, 4])
  .pipe(
    mergeAll(),
    concatMap(getItem),
    toArray()
  )
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```