# Combine nested HTTP requests in single observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a Workspace model, a Request model... and now a CatalogItem model which needs to combine the two like this:

```
{
  workspace: Workspace
  requests: Request[]
}
```

I'm having a bit of difficulty with how I should create this with a `getCatalog(): Observable<CatalogItem[]>` function... which should return a `CatalogItem` for each `Workspace`, with any associated `Request` added to it.

I realize my attempt is way off, but I'm hoping it's enough to help understand my intent:

```
getCatalog(): Observable<CatalogItem[]> {
  return this.http.get<Workspace[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/workspace`).pipe(
    switchMap( (ws) => {
      return {
        workspace: ws,
        requests: this.http.get<Request[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/${ws.id}/requests`).subscribe();
      }
    })
  );
  //TODO: combine workspace and request create catalog obj
}
```

Comment: To clarify, the second call is dependent on the result of the first call? (you can't have them run in parallel)

Comment: right, i'm attempting to do nested calls (the request calls can run in parallel after we get the workspace data)... but hoping to put this all together inside of getCatalog()... so /{workspace_id}/requests will add requests associated with each workspace that is returned from the /workspace call

Comment: I proposed a working answer below. Let me know if that's close to what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, it seems like you need to call `http.get<Request[]>` for each `workspace`.

**Here's how to implement it, simply follow the 3 steps below.**

**1.**
First use `mergeAll` to convert `Obsevable<Workspace[]>` (returned by `get<Workspace[]>`) into a stream (so we can handle one `workspace` at a time).

**2.**
Next use `mergeMap` to convert each `Observable<Workspace>` into `Observable<CatalogItem>` by calling `http.get<Request[]>` and forming a new `CtalogItem` once response arrived using `map` (utilizing closure to reference `workspace`).

**3.**
Finally convert the stream back into array using `toArray`.

```js
getCatalog(): Observable<CatalogItem[]> {
  return this.http.get<Workspace[]>(`URL/workspace`).pipe(

   // 1  
    mergeAll(),

   // 2  
    mergeMap(workspace => this.http.get<Request[]>(`URL/${workspace.id}`).pipe(
      map(requests => ({ workspace, requests })))
    ),

   // 3  
    toArray()

  )
}
```

`mergeAll` can flattens an Observable containing an array into a stream, for further explanation refer to [@Martin's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42482824/9369606) about the best way to “flatten” an array inside an RxJS Observable

`toArray` collects all source emissions and emits them as an array when the source completes.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's an example:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-essfmr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

The idea is to chain your requests so they are dependent on each other and have the result being a merged object of some sort like you have laid out.

The key (at least from my learnings on this) is the `toArray` at the *end* of the pipeline

```
  getTodos(): Observable<SomeMergedObject[]> {
    return this.http.get<TodoItem[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').pipe(
      mergeMap( resp => resp),
      concatMap( (t: TodoItem) => {
        console.log(t.userId)
        return this.http.get<User>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${t.userId}`).pipe(
          map( user => ({ todoItem: t, user } as SomeMergedObject))
        )
      }),
      toArray()
    );
  }
```

Interfaces

```
interface TodoItem {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

interface User {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  username: string,
  address: object,
  phone: string;
  website: string;
  company: object;
}

interface SomeMergedObject {
  todoItem: TodoItem;
  user: User;
}
```

Comment: looking at the interface for mergedObject... shouldn't `todoItem` be type `TodoItem[]`

Comment: In this example, I'm just getting back of of the todo's and getting the user (by Todo.UserId) and merging the two User/Todo objects. So, the result is actually `SomeMergedObject[]` but you could totally change that to be a return type of `TodoItem[]`. I just went with a merged object since that's what it looked like you were doing.

If you look at the stackblitz, there is a full, working example in there. Might take a second to fetch the data since it's doing a ton of HTTP requests.

Comment: i mean, SomeMergedObject.todoItem should really be an array (todoItems) as "requests" in my question. There could be 0 or many "todoItem" per "SomeMergedObject"

Comment: You can certainly change it that way. You can form an object any way you like. Are you saying that you are essentially not trying to map two different responses to each other but just trying to consolidate them into an object  `{ allResponsesForResponse1: [ <response1>, ... ], allResponsesForResponse2: [<response2>, ...] }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inner pipe to solve your problem:

```
getCatalog(): Observable<CatalogItem[]> {
  return this.http.get<Workspace[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/workspace`).pipe(
    switchMap(workspace => this.http.get<Request[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/${ws.id}/requests`).pipe(
      map(requests => ({workspace, request}))
    )
  );
}
```

Details:

- If you open another `pipe` inside the switchMap you still have the context of the switchMap. That means you can use the `workspace`.
- If your variable name is the key you want (e.g. `const key = 'test'`) as property you can shortwrite `{ key }`. This will create an object `{ key: 'test }`
- If you want to return an object inside a map you can shortwrite `({ ... })` instead of `{ return {} }`