# Chaining recursive RxJS observables while operating on object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

My backend has two graphql queries: `familiyTreeQuery` which returns a family tree as a node with children, which can also have children and so on, and `personPicturesQuery($name: string)` which returns pictures of the given person.

My goal is to call the `familyTreeQuery`, iterate the tree and if the person is called Alice, then I want to call the `personPicturesQuery` for the person and add the information to the node in the tree. This should be done for all Alices in the tree.

My problem is, that the call to fetch pictures happens asynchronous and the data is therefore returned before the information is added to the node.
I failed to use `flatMap` as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268482/chaining-rxjs-observables-from-http-data-in-angular2-with-typescript), because the call to fetch the pictures is happening while iterating the tree and I can't call it in the pipe method of the `familyTreeQuery`.

```js
public getContext(): Observable<TreeNode> {
  return this.familyTreeQuery.watch().valueChanges.pipe(
    map(result => {
      const familyTree = result.data.familyTree;;
      this.addPicturesToAlice(familyTree);
      return familyTree;
      
    })
  )
}

private addPicturesToAlice(node: TreeNode) {
  if (node.name === 'Alice') {
    this.fetchPictures(node.id).subscribe(pictures => {
      node.pictures = pictures;
    })
  }
  if (node.children && node.children.length > 0) {
    for (const childNode of node.children) {
      this.addPicturesToAlice(childNode);
    }
  }
}

private this.fetchPictures(personId): Observable<Picture[]> {
  return this.personPicturesQuery.fetch({id: personId}).pipe(
    map(result => {
      return result.data.personPictures;
    })
  )
}
```

From what I understand I'm not supposed to call subscribe in the `addPicturesToAlice` method, but I'm new to Angular and RxJS and didn't find a way to make this work.

Comment: where is `structuredTrees` defined?

Comment: was supposed to be `familyTree`, edited the question

Comment: You could consider swapping from Observable to Promise here and using the async-await approach.

Comment: The problem is that the `getContext()` method would need to be async and return a `Promise` but the methods calling `getContext()`  expect an `Observable` and I don't want to change the whole code base. But if there's no other way I may have to

Comment: Since `fetchPictrues()` takes no params, how do you expect it to fetch different pictures for each node?

Comment: As noted in the comment in the code, you can just pretend it does. I simplified the code for the question, in reality it handles other stuff

Comment: In order to answer your question it's quite necessary to unerstand how it does, so we can refactor `addPicturesToAlice`

Comment: I pass information saved in the node to `fetchPictures()`. I edited the code to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by creating an array of observables and passing it along recursively, then subscribing to it in `getContext` using `forkJoin`, as demonstrated below:

```
public getContext(): Observable<TreeNode> {
  return this.familyTreeQuery.watch().valueChanges.pipe(
    switchMap(({ data: { familyTree } }) => forkJoin(this.addPicturesToAlice(familyTree)))
  )
}

private addPicturesToAlice(node: TreeNode, observables: Observable<Picture[]>[] = []): Observable<Picture[]>[] {
  if (node.name === 'Alice') observables.push(
    this.fetchPictures(node.id).pipe(tap(pictures => node.pictures = pictures))
  )

  if (node.children?.length) {
    for (const childNode of node.children) {
      this.addPicturesToAlice(childNode, observables);
    }
  }

  return observables;
}

private fetchPictures(personId: number): Observable<Picture[]> {
  return this.personPicturesQuery
    .fetch({ id: personId })
    .pipe(map(result => result.data.personPictures))
}
```

Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Seems like this will work, thank you very much! One more question, how would I do it if the `familyTreeQuery` returns multiple familiyTrees? Is there another RxJS method I can use before the `switchMap`?

Comment: please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482705/best-way-to-flatten-an-array-inside-an-rxjs-observable/42482824#42482824