# Why rxjs' mergeMap turns array into separate objects

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am not Typescript, Javascript or frontend developer at all. I have inherited Angular 13 project. There is a function returning `Observable<Dto[]>`. I see something along this lines in the code:

```js
this.service.getStuff(arg).pipe(
    mergeMap(x => x),
    concatMap(y => { return this.service.getOtherStuff(x.subObj.id).pipe(
        map(v => ({ obj1: y, obj2: v})));
    })
).subscribe(
// ... do something with results
```

I understand what it does and why it does that, but I can't for the life of me understand why would `mergeMap` turn an array into a stream of separate values. [Documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap) says only that `mergeMap`:

```
Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output Observable
```

My understanding is that `source value` in this case is `Dto[]`, so projection should be `Observable<Dto[]>`, not a list of Observables created from separate values in the array.

I suspected that *maybe* this maneuver is done later, but putting `tap` with `console.log` around `mergeMap` shows that input is indeed an array and output is a stream objects.

So what is happening and why? And why isn't it explained in the documentation while we're at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intended behavior. If you look at the documnetation it says that the `project` function needs to return [`ObservableInput`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/type-alias/ObservableInput) and not just `Observable`. In fact, all RxJS operators that expect an Observable as a parameter will work with any `ObservableInput`.

`ObservableInput` can be for example an Observable (obviously), async generator, an array or a Promise.

So using `mergeMap(x => x)` is really only used to unwrap the array and is equivalent to `mergeMap(x => from(x))`. Maybe more clean solution would be using just `mergeAll()` operator that is intended to be used with higher-order Observables.

Comment: What I don't understand is why `ArrayLike<T>` (because I think this is the case here) is unwrapped - or rather I understand that it might be by design, but is it written anywhere? I couldn't find it on https://rxjs.dev/.

Comment: Ok, here https://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObservableInputDoc.html it is written explicitly. But how are rxjs.dev and reactivex.io connected if at all - that I don't know.

Comment: The official docs is rxjs.dev. I don't know who maintains reactivex.io.

Comment: Weird, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReactiveX says that reactivex.io is Microsoft's effort. What is most interesting is that documentation seems much richer - if I haven't limited my search to rxjs.dev, which is an official site as you said, I would have found answer to my question on my own. Never the less thanks for an answer.

Comment: rxjs.dev is a part of the RxJS github repo. I think that reactivex.io is a general documentation about Rx principles shared among all implementations. I'm just looking at the examples with RxJS they have and it's very outdated (most are probably for RxJS 5 or older). But you're right, the documentation (including the official one) is sometimes very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you are using `mergeMap` not how it is normally intended. The map operators like `mergeMap` or `switchMap` expect an Observable (or a Promise) as the return value. But you are just returning the plain array. It seems like `mergeMap` sees that this is not an Observable and wraps it in a `from` operator. This creates an Observable from the array where each element emits individually.

If you do not want this behavior, wrap your value in `of`.

```
mergeMap(x => of(x))
```

But really this `mergeMap` does not have any effect either way. Why are you using this do-nothing function here? If you don't plan to return an Observable, why not use a `map`?

Comment: As I mentioned this is not something that I wrote, this is something I "inherited" from different company. Why is it done this way - I don't know, but I've seen it mentioned as a solution quite a few times here on SO (see for example this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482705/best-way-to-flatten-an-array-inside-an-rxjs-observable). Also this is not something I want or not, I wanted to know why it behaves like this because it is counter-intuitive. As a side note, how would you change that? `mergeMap(x => from(x))`? I want it to be more explicit, since it works fine either way.

Answer (score 1):

I have accepted @martin's answer as it allowed me to find an answer in the documentation - but not on https://rxjs.dev site but rather on https://reactivex.io site. As @martin pointed out, what `project` function should return is `ObservableInput`, which is defined as:

```js
type ObservableInput<T> = Observable<T> | InteropObservable<T> | AsyncIterable<T> | PromiseLike<T> | ArrayLike<T> | Iterable<T> | ReadableStreamLike<T>;
```

Part `ArrayLike<T>` is the key and on [reactivex.io](https://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js%7EObservableInputDoc.html) we can read more (and I couldn't find this **VERY** important piece of info on https://rxjs.dev site), most importantly:

> **Array** Arrays can be interpreted as observables that emit all values in array one by one, from left to right, and then complete
> immediately.
>
> **Array-like** Arrays passed to operators do not have to be built-in JavaScript Arrays. They can be also, for example, arguments property
> available inside every function, DOM NodeList, or, actually, any
> object that has length property (which is a number) and stores values
> under non-negative (zero and up) integers.

This piece of information is of paramount importance and I can't believe it is not written in the docs on the other site.